# Session Storage in js

Tags: javascript

Hi i'm a beginner in JavaScript i would like to ask if its possible to session the data i'm getting from a server. The data i want to session is the 'data.xhr.response' i searched online that most people use the SessionStorage function but i'm not really sure how to go about it any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
$(function() 
{
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$('#file-upload').dropzone({
    maxFiles: 1,
    acceptedFiles: ".pdf,.doc,.docx,.html", 
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data.xhr.response);

    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Session storage is same as local storage but the only difference is that data stored in session storage will clear automatically once page session will expire.

Now come to your question. In your `success` function, do like below to store data:

```
success : function(data) {
    console.log(data.xhr.response);
    sessionStorage.setItem('dataStored', data.xhr.response);

}
```

Usage is like below:

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('dataStored', data.xhr.response);

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('dataStored');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('dataStored');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

For more information about `sessionStorage` check this link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: Does sessionStorage only store key value objects?

Comment: value can be anything

Comment: store anything, I use it to store values I need to pass to multiple services in the request header, such as user's email for example. If you're using vuex, you can use vuex-persist to save state in localStorage, too.

Answer (score 6):

In your case you can either to choose sessionStorage or localStorage. Both can save the data response for you in the browser. The difference is only the expiry that localStorage wont expire while sessionStorage stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser tab is closed).

So the steps are:

1. Check your browser to see if it supports webStorage:

   ```
   if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
       // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
   } else {
       // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
   }
   ```
2. Implement localStorage:

   ```
   localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");  // save data
   var user = localStorage.getItem("lastname"); // get data
   localStorage.removeItem("lastname");  // remove data
   ```
3. Implement sessionStorage:

   ```
   sessionStorage.setItem('lastname', 'Smith'); // save data
   var user = sessionStorage.getItem('lastname'); // get data
   sessionStorage.removeItem('dataStored');  // remove data
   ```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

Try reading this article about session storage on [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), it shows how straightforward it is. In your case it should be as simple as:

```
$('#file-upload').dropzone({
  maxFiles: 1,
  acceptedFiles: ".pdf,.doc,.docx,.html", 
  dataType: "json",
  success : function(data) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('xhr', data.xhr.response);
  }
});
```