# How to preserve previous HTML when back button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched the related question but couldn't relate to my question.

I am developing one app with HTML & JQuery. One HTML page like "Catalog" will display the products dynamically (e.g. On page load will show 20 products & with "Load More" button will add another 20 products & so on). If user click on "View Details" link of product no. 45 then page will redirect to new HTML for detail view of the product. Not if user click on back button how to view "Catelog" HTML page as same as user leave before without any server call?

If anyone knows please share your idea or any plugins available?

Thanks..!!!

Comment: Sorry but without any server call it's impossible, you'll make a new http request by clicking on the back button. What you can do is the View detail inside a modal without redirecting to a new url, if it's possible.

Comment: Instead of redirecting, you can show the details of the product in the same page.

Comment: You just swap pages/containers/divs display:none and display:block styles

Comment: are you talking about back button of browser or back button in detail page?

Comment: @CerlinBoss If its same page and if i press browser back button. do it handle in same page? or it will redirect to my some other HTML page say Menu or dashboard HTML?

Comment: @Khushbu talking about browser back button or back button in detail page. it should work same.

Comment: try adding `window.history.back()` on the back button click event

Comment: @Snehal You can use `window.history.replaceState` to change the url to a new one when u show the details of the product. If this is done, browser will go back to previous url (without reloading) when the user clicks the back button of browser.

Answer (score 0):

So. i have i have idea to implement, that you can Store Number of products loaded by user in javascript session storage. so like user views 60 products by clicking load more multiple times. so store the 60 value. and you can check id session storage has value already you can load more intially.

So User will return from product view it you will find session storage 60 is there and you can make it loaded again.

To Save Session Storage
[Session Storage in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50458409/session-storage-in-js)

Comment: Yes i have read the same. Have you implemented in your any site? I need to implement & check. Thanks for the response.

Comment: how are you loading more products in list. using ajax?

Comment: Yes with $.ajax

Comment: what variable you are passing for load more??

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Its yet to implement. I will let you know once its get implemented.

Comment: my idea seems to work like if user go to wherever and comes to products list page and if he used to came and visit 60 product. it will load 60 product again. not only for back button.

Comment: Yes i understand. If user make any filter from filter page then it will start from beginning (first 20 products) other wise 60 products.

Comment: Okay. Cool. Will Share fiddle for you quickly.

Answer (score -1):

So, If you want previous page with out server call , Simply use        **window.history.back();**   on click event.

this is like **"back button"** in your browse.