# Send input form data to login form on different page (HTML/js)

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, cookies, session-cookies

I have a 2-part login where you enter your username on the first page, then, the second page opens via `window.open()` and I want to autofill the username data from the first page into the username field on the second page.

Here's my code (1st page):

```
    const $document = $(document);
        const $login = $("#login");
        const $loginBox = $("#loginbox");

        const $formElement = $(`
          <div class="loginContainer">
            <label for="userNameBox"><b>Username: </b></label>
            <input type="text" class="userName"id="userNameBox" placeholder="Enter Username"required="required">
            <input type="button" class="loginButton" id="loginButton" value="Login"/>
          </div>
        `);

        $document.on("click", "#loginButton", function() {
          const $userNameBox = $("#userNameBox");

          if ($userNameBox.val() !== "") {
            window.open('secondPage.com','_blank');
          } else {
            alert("Please Enter a Username.");
            location.reload();
          }
        });

          $('.login').click(function(e) {

          if ($loginBox.children().length === 0) {
            $loginBox.append($formElement);

          }

          $("#loginbox").show();

          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
        });
```

The second page is just a standard login page with username and password fields and are set up like `<input type="text" id="USERNAME2" name="USERNAME2" placeholder="username" class="text_field item" >`

Can I use a session cookie to somehow send the form data over to the second page?

Answer (score 1):

As a backend developer we stores the temporary information in the session and you can get the help of storing sessions in js in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50458409/session-storage-in-js#:%7E:text=Session%20storage%20is%20same%20as,once%20page%20session%20will%20expire.&text=In%20your%20case%20you%20can,for%20you%20in%20the%20browser.)
And when the next page is loaded then you can load the session data using the same process.

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('dataStored', data.xhr.response);

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('dataStored');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('dataStored');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```